# angular + webpack: "Hot Module Replacement is disabled" error after build

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having a problem with a pretty straight forward webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
    path = require('path');

var PATHS = {
    app: __dirname + "/app"
};

var config = {
    context: PATHS.app,
entry: {
    app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server',  './core/bootstrap.js']
}
,

// entry: './core/bootstrap.js',

output: {
    path: PATHS.app,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'ng-annotate!babel', exclude: /node_modules/},
        {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less", exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/},  
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json", exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/},
        {test: /\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "raw"},
        {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/, loader: "file"},
        {test: /\.woff(2)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"}

    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        ON_TEST: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
    })
],

devtool: "#inline-source-map"

}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    config.output.path = __dirname + '/dist';
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
}

module.exports = config;
```

I'm trying to build a minified version of my code and but when I'm running 
`NODE_ENV=production node node_modules/.bin/webpack && cp app/index.html dist/index.html` there is no `bundle.min.js` in my dist folder and when I'm running `http-server dist` I'm getting `Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.`

From going through the web I see that this is a common problem but nowhere did I find the way to fix this: I'm  using the `--hot` flag that suppose to add the hot-swap plugin.

Comment: since, you are using `http-server`, you can remove `webpack-dev-server` entry point from `entry: {
    app: [ './core/bootstrap.js']
}`

Comment: Thanks that helped but now I have a problem with angular and minification (due to name change of the parameters - provider not found issue) although I used ng-annotate loader on my js loader.